# Debugging nodejs while using Kinesis MultiLangDaemon/KCL

Tags: node.js, amazon-kinesis

Following [this post](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx18TQUE4BLLE5F/Processing-Amazon-Kinesis-Stream-Data-Using-Amazon-KCL-for-Node-js) I was able to connect our existing nodejs code into Kinesis logs (using KCL and MultiLangDaemon).

The problem is that I can't debug the code anymore.
Since MultiLangDaemon uses STDIN/STDOUT to interact with executed "script", once I call "node --debug" and get the message:

> "debugger listening on port 57846"

I get an error from the MultiLangDaemon saying:

> "SEVERE: Received error line from subprocess [debugger listening on port 57846] for shard shardId-000000000000"

- Is there a way to execute nodejs "quietly", so it won't send this STDERR message ?
- Does anyone have experience with MultiLangDaemon and debugging ?

Thanks,
Shushu

Comment: Did you consider using AWS Lambda (http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) instead? Easier integration and you can also use CloudWatch Logs to easily debug/monitor it.

Comment: Thanks. No, I didn't. Logs is nice, but getting proper debug information while running always gives me much more.
Regardless, Using Lambda should be interesting.

Comment: 3 years later and Lambdas are still the best for interfacing with Kinesis. anything else is nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer in [here](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx18TQUE4BLLE5F/Processing-Amazon-Kinesis-Stream-Data-Using-Amazon-KCL-for-Node-js), recommending to work with node inspector.
After installing, all I had to do is to change the kinesis.properties executableName from "node" to "node-debug", and I got it working.